# Team foundation server, how to view all files checked in on a given day in a project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project using TFS source control. I am very new to TFS, does anyone know a way that I can see all files checked in on a give day? Thank you

Comment: If you want just a list of files, you will have to use the API. Everything you can get to without the API is in View History.

Answer (score 0):

try this tool

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\TFPT.EXE" searchcs

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio:

Open Source Control Explorer, right-click the project folder and select **View History.** ({This will list all the ChangeSets)

Then click the **Compare Folders** icon to bring up the **Compare** dialog

In this dialog, set the Target Path equal to the Source Path, and select Type = Date for both.

For the Source Path, set the Date equal to the start of the day that you are querying, and for the Target Path set the Date equal to the start of the day.

In the View Options, tick the first three boxes. Here is an example where I am searching for all changesets added yesterday to a particular project.

[image]

Click OK. This will then show all the changes to the files in the Changesets that were added during the day.